# Using regular expression to extract full words from text

Tags: regex

I have been working with parsing data, I got a string like:

```
"Scottish Premier League (click here to open|close this coupon)"
```

I would like to extract "Scottish Premier League" with *`Scottish`* Matching Group 1 and *`Premier League`* Matching Group 2, using regular expression.

Please show me the way to do that using regular expression.

```
MatchCollection matchCol = reg.Matches("Scottish Premier League (click here to open|close this coupon)");
```

Comment: Other than Regex, which language will be used to be the "glue" which makes the parser work ?   Also, you will likely not limit yourself to this one Scottish Premier League, are there may similar keywords / patterns... ?

Comment: What it the criteria here? If it's just the first word, you don't need regular expressions. Anything more than that, however, is almost natural language processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to match each specific word then your regex could be something like:

```
(Scottish) (Premier League)
```

If you want to match the first word then the next two:

```
([\w]+) ([\w]+ [\w]+)
```

Another way of writing this that accounts for multiple spaces between words is:

```
(\w+)\s+(\w+\s+\w+)
```

Comment: This solution i would recommend. Works perfectly.

Comment: This is better written as `/^(\w+) (\w+ \w+)/` because there's no need to put the square brackets around a single character and you only want the starting part of the string not, for example, "here", "to open"

Answer (score 1):

/(Scottish) (Premier League)/

Comment: I have to fix location is Scottish and then I can get division Premier League after replace Scottish => empty.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Basic and direct:

```
$s =  "Scottish Premier League (click ... coupon)";
$s =~ m/(Scottish) (Premier League)/;
print "Match groups one and two: '$1' '$2'\n";
```

You probably wanted more generalized matching:

```
$s =  "Generalized Matching on a string (click ... coupon)";
$s =~ m/^(\S+)\s(.+)\s+\(click/;
print "Match groups one and two: '$1' '$2'\n";
```

These are Perl; be more specific next time.

Also, help yourself, use a tool, like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/demo.html) or [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: I set -1 before you edited (within the 5min margin), and now it won't let me change, sorry. Though why do you include the first (apparently completely jocular) example?

Comment: @R. Pate. Totally not a problem; you'll learn to wait to down vote when an answer is a day old or more. To answer your question: Because it is correct. I do not play guessing games to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you only gave one string to which the regex would be applied, it is hard to tell if this solution would work for your various other cases:

```
/^(\w*) (.*) \(/
```